# Make command repeat Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have this discord.js code that when i run "!cat" it sends a random image from r/cats here is the code:

```
var Discord = require('discord.js');
var bot = new Discord.Client()
randomPuppy = require('random-puppy') 

bot.on('ready', function() {
    console.log(bot.user.username);
});

bot.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content === "!cat") { 
            const img = await randomPuppy('cats')
            message.channel.send(img);
         
    }
});
```

I want it to send this every 20 mins instead of when a user uses the command. I have found a few ways but they do not work in an aysync. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you just use `setInterval()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try using setInterval() like so:

```
setInterval(async function(){
     client.channels.cache.get(channelID).send("Whatever you want to send")
}, 1200000)
```

This does whatever is inside every 1200000 ms or 20 mins. I would put this is in the `client.once("ready")` bit. Note that you won't have access to the message, and you'll just have to send the message to a specific channel.

Here's the full working implementation

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
randomPuppy = require("random-puppy");

//Place your channelID here. You should be able to find it by: 
//Enabling Developer mode in your discord app(User Settings > Advanced> Developer mode)
//Right click the channel you want the messages to send to and tap "copy id"
channelID = "channelID";

prefix = "!";

//This fires as soon as your bot is "ready"
client.once('ready', ()=>{
    console.log("Bot is Active!");

    //Here's the meat of it. setInterval repeats the function every "interval" milliseconds. 
    //Note that it doesn't fire the first time 
    //Set the interval to something smaller, like 10000, to see if it works
    setInterval(async function(){

        //The code you want to run
        const img = await randomPuppy('cats');
        client.channels.cache.get(channelID).send(img);
        
    }, 1200000);

    //Further reassurance
    console.log("This should print");
});

//Added this bit for further context, nothing useful in here
client.on("message", async message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === "test"){
        message.channel.send("Despite your best efforts, I am still alive...");    
    }
});

client.login('BOT_TOKEN_HERE');
```

Comment: im sorry im really new to this, can you show more of the code and where to put in. This is not working for me and giving me the error SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

```client.once('ready', async message => {
setInterval(function(){
            const img = await randomPuppy('cats')
            message.channel.send(img);
}, 10000)
});
```

Comment: Your `setInterval()` function isn't async. `setInterval(async function(){...}, 10000)`

Comment: Okay I added code that works on my end, at least. Also added the async keyword to make the inside async. I had a lot of trouble the first time scheduling tasks too, and still am a bit of a beginner at this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I am super appreciative of your work! I marked your answer as correct as well 